# SQL case operation

Tags: sql

Im fairly new with sql, and been trying to solve a problem where you have a table information about orders. In this case, Im trying to use the case operation to get a monthly report on orders, so I should have a column which states the year,another one which states the month, and then I should have columns for days 1-20,21-22,23-24 and above 25. Im trying to use the case operation to get the amount of orders that happened on those days.
I tried the following query :

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(YEAR,date) AS year,DATEPART(MONTH,date) AS month,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,date) BETWEEN 1 AND 20 THEN order ELSE 0 END) AS D1_D20,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,date) BETWEEN 21 AND 22 THEN order ELSE 0 END) AS D21_D22,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,date) BETWEEN 23 AND 24 THEN order ELSE 0 END) AS D23_D24,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,date) > 25 THEN order ELSE 0 END) AS D25_END
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,date),DATEPART(MONTH,date)
```

Obviously the problem with that query is that, now I just get the total number of orders for each of the days, I know I should count the orders, but dont know the syntax. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUM()`:

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(YEAR, date) AS year, DATEPART(MONTH, date) AS month,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,date) BETWEEN 1 AND 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS D1_D20,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,date) BETWEEN 21 AND 22 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS D21_D22,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,date) BETWEEN 23 AND 24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS D23_D24,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,date) > 25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS D25_END
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, date), DATEPART(MONTH, date);
```

I would recommend using the functions `DAY()`, `YEAR()`, and `MONTH()` because they are simpler to type.

By the way, you can use `COUNT()` if you remove the `ELSE` clause.  Your particular problem is that `COUNT(0) = COUNT(1)` because `COUNT()` counts non-`NULL` values.  I prefer `SUM()` because it is  more intuitive in this respect.